# Plotting User Locations On A Map in an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, xcode, geolocation, mapkit

How can I receive and store user location data so that I can add it to a map?

Have been studying MapKit and the UserLocation code from Apple. What I want to do is get all user's locations and plot on a map - a worldmap with dots showing the combined user base locations - like several apps we've all seen. NOT looking for code, need to do my own work, just if someone could share how they would tackle this..Thanks! Do I gather the user location somehow - add to a plist and .... Not sure...

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: Very new to this - trying to understand how to ask - I need to get user location from say 100 users, plot on a map for all to see - can you describe the process?  (make any sense?) Is the world map in a webview that is updated on data received from the iPhone?

Comment: @Bob, please read the SO FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq You should ask specific programming questions here. This is not the place to ask someone to write a tutorial for you (which is the best guess I have for what you are asking).

Comment: Not at all - Just didn't want to ask for code, trying to be easy and just ask for an overview - very poorly asked - apologies!  May I ask how a developer actually receives user location data so that they may add it to a map? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but what sort of answer are you looking for if not code to do it? Have you read the documentation for MapKit? That's the best place to begin.

Comment: Thank you - that's actually it! - Just to know that yes it's possible within MapKit - and I'll find the answer there - I'll study it some more - thought there might be somewhere else I needed to be looking!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the Core Location APIs as well as map kit, you can find a way to get user locations there. Store the results in an array, with a plist to save them if you want, and put annotations on your map to show all locations.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're going to need to build a couple web services:
1) that the assorted clients can send their location data TO, and that will then store it in a database. Then
2) when any user needs to open the map view, they'll request the full set of data so that you can then use that data to plot the points